# How to restrict buttons on codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, model-view-controller

can you guys help me?

I want to make the button on the "Pengajuan Judul" menu active/exist when the status on the "Verifikasi TA" menu is received. if on the "Verifikasi TA" menu the data is rejected/not verified then the button on the "Pengajuan Judul" menu does not exist/disabled.

do you guys have a solution for me?
I've tried but the result is still the same.
thankyouu, have a nice day :)

View Pengajuan Judul

```
    <?php if ($verifikasi_ta['status'] == 'Diterima') : ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <a href="<?= base_url('akademik/tambahpengajuan'); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
            </div>
        </div><br>
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="alert alert-primary d-flex align-items-center" role="alert">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-exclamation-triangle-fill flex-shrink-0 me-2" viewBox="0 0 16 16" role="img" aria-label="Warning:">
                <path d="M8.982 1.566a1.13 1.13 0 0 0-1.96 0L.165 13.233c-.457.778.091 1.767.98 1.767h13.713c.889 0 1.438-.99.98-1.767L8.982 1.566zM8 5c.535 0 .954.462.9.995l-.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 1-1.1 0L7.1 5.995A.905.905 0 0 1 8 5zm.002 6a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z" />
            </svg>
            <div>
                Not Found
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Controller Pengajuan Judul

```
 public function pengajuanjudul()
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('role_id') == 2) {
            $owner_id = $this->User_Model->getid($this->session->userdata('email'));
            $data['title'] = 'Mhs - Pengajuan Judul TA';
            $data['verifikasi_ta'] = $this->Verifikasi_Model->getVerifikasi_ownerid_acc($owner_id)->result_array();
            $data['pengajuan_judul'] = $this->Pengajuan_Model->getAllPengajuan();
            $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();
        } else {
            $data['title'] = 'Pengajuan Judul TA';
            $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();
        }
        $data['verifikasi_ta'] = $this->db->get_where('verifikasi_ta', ['status'])->row_array();
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
        $this->load->view('akademik/pengajuanjudul', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

[pengajuan menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45nnS.png)
[verifikasi menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1guo.png)

Comment: which button do you want to be disabled? and whats the trigger for a button to be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    <?php if ($verifikasi_ta['status'] == "Diterima"){ ?>
         // your button here ....
    <?php }else{ ?>
         // your alert here ...
    <?php } ?>
```

Also check your database field content, "Diterima" or "diterima"?
You also can check "Diterima" field content in your controller before, than write php condition script in view.